# VS Code syntax highlighting

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code for Python on a Mac. The syntax highlighting is very buggy for me. With the dark modern theme, I see:

[image: Image of the problem (example code)]

While class names, built-in functions and function names (when defining the functions are colored, most of the other code is simply white. I expected function calls to be of a different color than variables.

Other themes have the same problem. What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Post the image.

Comment: Oh, my bad - thought it had uploaded. I added the image

Comment: Please check out: "Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?" - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: @AntonKesy not especially relevant, since it's specifically to do with how VS Code renders it

Comment: "While class names, built-in functions and function names (when defining the functions are colored, most of the other stuff is simply white." - I don't understand the problem. **What other colours do you think you should see**, on what other elements of the code, and why? Why is "most of the other stuff is simply white" wrong?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel sorry for my not very precise question! I expected function calls to be of a different color than variables. The answer by Miguel fixed it though.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clarify that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have the Python extension installed, and are using the Default Modern theme (which supports this colorization), then perhaps you've disabled "semantic token color customizations" (`editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations`).

When my `settings.json` contains this:

```json
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "enabled": false
},
```

My code looks like this:

[image: Image of Python code in VS Code, with semantic token color customizations disabled]

When I remove this setting from my `settings.json`, the colors are returned to normal:

[image: Image of Python code in VS Code, with semantic token color customizations enabled]

Some other settings to check are:

- Token color customizations (`editor.tokenColorCustomizations`)
- Color customizations (`workbench.colorCustomizations`)
- Your color theme - `Dark (Visual Studio)` looks almost identical, but doesn't have semantic token color customizations.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! There was some weird stuff going on in the "editor.tokenColorCustomizations". Thanks for your help, have a great weekend! :)

Answer (score 0):

Please fallow [this tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial). It will solve most of your issues, show you how to work with virtual environments and configure extensions.

TLDR - download python extension and everything will work out of the box. Other useful extensions are ruff and black:

1. [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) - most of intellisense and lang support.
2. [Black](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.black-formatter) -formatter
3. [Ruff](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=charliermarsh.ruff) - linter with superpowers. Can also sort imports, format code

As alternative you could also try [pyCharm community edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/) - it's free tool specifically created for working with python which works out of the box with 0 configuration.